# Kendo Ui edit listview with mvc wrappers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Is there an example available for Kendo Listview CRUD with mvc wrappers. The demo on kendo site helps a lot but the editor doesn't  open up when I click the edit button on my list item. The deletion works ok. Probably I don't know how to set its editor template. Please let me know the steps involved to set the editor template.

Comment: Are you talking about this control: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/listview/editing.html ? We need to see your code to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The examples for the MVC Wrappers should also be available on your local machine. If you have used the windows installer of the extensions then inside **program files/telerik/mvc kendo** there should be demos which you can run and compare to your case.